# Alterar a cor do texto de um botão via XML ao clicar nele

Tags: android, button, android-xml, android-styles

Boa tarde !
  Estou criando uma styleGuides para uma aplicação android e estou com dificuldade para alterar a cor do texto do botão ao no momento em que o mesmo é clicado pelo usuário:
  Nesse exemplo estou criando um padão do botao de cancelar, onde, inicialmente a cor do texto é vermelha, o texto é cancelar (style) e ao ser pressionado o mesmo recebe uma alteração nas bordas e seu background muda para vermelho(drawable) e é nesse momento que eu preciso que a cor do texto também mude, nesse caso para BRANCO, segue códigos mencionados:
Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_cancel"
    style="@style/CancelButton"/>
```

Style:

```
<!-- Button Cancel Theme -->
<style name="CancelButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorCancel</item>
    <item name="android:text">Cancelar</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Drawable(Background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorCancel" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorCancel" />

    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Do jeito que está só está faltando mudar a cor do texto ao botão ser clicado, gostaria de fazer isso via XML mesmo para poder usar como biblioteca de padrão para o App. Se tiverem alguma dica de melhoria ficarei feliz em saber!